# using python, Remove HTML tags/formatting from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that contains html markup like links, bold text, etc.

I want to strip all the tags so I just have the raw text.

What's the best way to do this? regex?

Answer (score 64):

If you are going to use regex:

```
import re
def striphtml(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)

>>> striphtml('<a href="foo.com" class="bar">I Want This <b>text!</b></a>')
'I Want This text!'
```

Comment: This will only work reliably on well-formed HTML (ie, no unescaped `<` or `>` outside of actual tags, no malformed tags like `<b class="forgot-to-close"`, etc.).  That being said, this is the first approach I'd use, depending on the source data.

Comment: Please add more clarification as to the very limited situations where that would be a good idea and I'll remove my down-vote. Thank you.

Comment: plus this will also the remove the following text => "if 3 < 5 then 5 > 3"

Answer (score 13):

Use lxml.html. It's much faster than BeautifulSoup and raw text is a single command.

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> page = lxml.html.document_fromstring('<!DOCTYPE html>...</html>')
>>> page.cssselect('body')[0].text_content()
'...'
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Use this snippet for extracting text from HTML fragments: `lxml.html.fromstring('some HTML fragment').text_content()`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using regex to parse HTML (especially directly of the internet) is a VERY **bad** idea!

Comment: This simply strips all HTML code and replaces it with nothing, it would be nice if it inserted appropriate line breaks so you didnt end up with a single line of nonsense

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK using regex is a bad idea for parsing HTML, you would be better off
 using a HTML/XML parser like [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: +1 for Beautiful Soup

Comment: I am using beautifulsoup, but I want to be able to strip html tags manually also. thanks!

Comment: @Blankman it would of been a good idea to mention that in your question

Comment: He's not parsing HTML, he's removing tags. Parsing HTML/XML is very slow, often the slowest aspect of applications that use it, so I would not recommend BeautifulSoup for this. 

HTML parsing cannot be done with regex because regexes do not have stacks (LIFOs), and HTML can be arbitrarily nested, which requires a stack to parse.

Comment: Why is beautiful soup better for html parsing? I use regexes myself. Have I missed the light? Thanks.

Comment: well kind of depends on the situation tho...

Answer (score 3):

Use `SGMLParser`. `regex` works in simple case. But there are a lot of intricacy with HTML you rather not have to deal with.

```
>>> from sgmllib import SGMLParser
>>>
>>> class TextExtracter(SGMLParser):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.text = []
...         SGMLParser.__init__(self)
...     def handle_data(self, data):
...         self.text.append(data)
...     def getvalue(self):
...         return ''.join(ex.text)
...
>>> ex = TextExtracter()
>>> ex.feed('<html>hello &gt; world</html>')
>>> ex.getvalue()
'hello > world'
```

Comment: Thanks, have been looking a while for such a solution requiring no external dependency. Changing *''.join(ex.text)* into *''.join(self.text)* made it suitable even as a stand-alone class.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether the text will contain '>' or '<' I would either just make a function to remove anything between those, or use a parsing lib

```
def cleanStrings(self, inStr):
  a = inStr.find('<')
  b = inStr.find('>')
  if a < 0 and b < 0:
    return inStr
  return cleanString(inStr[a:b-a])
```