# Python: How to delete a HTML header from a text string?

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using python, Remove HTML tags/formatting from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398852/using-python-remove-html-tags-formatting-from-a-string)

I read in a HTML file:

```
fi = open("Tree.html", "r")
text = fi.read()
```

I want to delete the HTML header from the text:

```
text = re.sub("<head>.*?</head>", "", text)
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: can you post the header portion from your html file.

Comment: Must read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not catching newlines. You need to add the DOTALL flag.

```
text = re.sub("<head>.*?</head>", "", text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Error message: TypeError: sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'

Comment: What version of python are you using? flags keyword is v2.7+.

Comment: I am using Python v2.6. Without "flags=" it works. Thanks!