# How do I preserve new lines when extracting text from html using lxml.text_content()

Tags: python, html, lxml, whoosh

I am trying to learn to use Whoosh.  I have a large collection of html documents I want to search.  I discovered that the text_content() method creates some interesting problems for example I might have some text that is organized in a table that looks like

```
<html><table><tr><td>banana</td><td>republic</td></tr><tr><td>stateless</td><td>person</td></table></html>
```

When I take the original string and and get the tree and then use text_content to get the text in the following manner

```
mytree = html.fromstring(myString)
text = mytree.text_content()
```

The results have no spaces (as should be expected)

'bananarepublicstatelessperson'

I tried to insert new lines using string.replace()

```
myString = myString.replace('</tr>','</tr>\n')
```

I confirmed that the new line was present

```
'<html><table><tr><td>banana</td><td>republic</td></tr>\n<tr><td>stateless</td><td>person</td></table></html>'
```

but when I run the same code from above the line feeds are not present.  Thus the resulting text_content() looks just like above.
This is a problem from me because I need to be able to separate words, I thought I could add non-breaking spaces after each td and line breaks after rows as well asd line breaks after body elements etc to get text that reasonably conforms to my original source.

I will note that I did some more testing and found that line breaks inserted after paragraph tag closes were preserved.  But there is a lot of text in the tables that I need to be able to search.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score -1):

You could use this solution:

```
import re
def striphtml(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)

>>> striphtml('<a href="foo.com" class="bar">I Want This <b>text!</b></a>')
>>> 'I Want This text!'
```

Found here: [using python, Remove HTML tags/formatting from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398852/using-python-remove-html-tags-formatting-from-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have always read that one should avoid reg expressions for handling html.  I was aware of this possibility but have avoided it and would probably resort to a manual approach using lxml before I did this.  That is I would process each element sequentially as they are found and use rules

Comment: Your answer led me to html2text which I think is a better start so I marked up